# How can I access this json response object?

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, object

I have tried many different ways to access "main". I have tried info.main, info["main"], info["- main"], I can't figure out how to access it and I continue to get "temp" of undefined. Info.base works just fine.

Here is an image of the state inside my components on google chrome. [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHkU3.png]

Here is what it looks like in json format [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0KAm.png]

Why is info.main.temp not working, but info.base is?
If i remove the h1 info.main.temp the page renders just fine, as soon as I put it back the app crashes.

```
function Body(props) {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState({});
  const [info, setInfo] = useState({});

  function getGeo() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
      setLocation({
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        long: position.coords.longitude,
      });
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getGeo();
    if (location.lat === undefined || location.long === undefined) {
      return;
    }
    fetch(
      `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${location.lat}&lon=${location.long}&units=metric&appid=key`
    )
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((result) => {
        setInfo(result);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, [location.lat, location.long, setInfo]);
return (
    <>
      <img className="adv" src="image1.png" />
      <div className="grid-block-container">
        <div className="city-weather">
          <div className="info-container">
            <h2>{info.base} Weather</h2>
            <p>as of 10:31 pm CDT</p>
            <h1>{info.main.temp}&#176;</h1>
            <h2>Party Cloudy</h2>
            <h3>10% chance of rain through 11pm</h3>
          </div>
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you are making the API call to get the information? Are you getting any error?

Comment: Show where you called setInfo

Comment: No errors at all from the api, as you can see in the first image, its setting to state just fine in my componnets, it just wont let me access info.main for some reason. Its like it only lets me access the keys that are orange, everything else is undefined.

Comment: updated it, but how can that be the reason if info.base works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial state is an empty object (`{}`)

```
const [info, setInfo] = useState({});
```

so accessing `base` or `main` of that object is ok and each would initially be `undefined` on the first renders until state is updated, but trying to go deeper, i.e. `info.main.temp` will result in the error.

```js
const info = {};

console.log('info', info); // {}
console.log('info.base', info.base); // undefined
console.log('info.main', info.main); // undefined
console.log('info.main.temp', info.main.temp); // error!!
```

You can use a guard on the deeper property

```
info.main && info.main.temp
```

Or use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to check if `main` exists before continuing on to `temp`

```
info.main?.temp
```

In either case you likely also want to provide a fallback value so `undefined` or `null`, etc.. aren't leaked out to the UI

```
(info.main && info.main.temp) || "Loading..."
```

or

```
(info.main && info.main.temp) || ""
```

or

```
info.main?.temp || ""
```

etc...

```js
const info = {};

console.log('info', info); // {}
console.log('info.main.temp', info.main?.temp); // undefined
console.log('info.main.temp', info.main?.temp || 'fallback'); // fallback
```

Comment: Never heard of optional chaining, that is a very neat option & looks like it can be very handy in special cases such as mine.

Comment: @Jayg713 It sure is, I was excited when it was finally rolled into create-react-app and became mainstream.